# Xcode 4: how to set the build location for OSX command line application only?

Tags: xcode4

By default Xcode 4 will compile and put the final executable in the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ directory.

I am happy to use this location for my iOS app, but can I change this setting on per project basis when I write an OSX command line app? (i.e. I do not want to modify XCode-> Preference-> Location because it will be applied globally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Goto Project Navigator (Command + 1)
2. File -> Project Settings...
3. Under "Build" tab's second section, titled as "Build Location", you will get your desire fields to configure.